# how to expose hidden arrow objects from indicator in chart objects lists

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql5, metatrader5

I have an indicator that draws arrows on the chart as seen in the image below:

[image]

I tried searching for the arrow objects in `Object List` but there were no objects there. I also checked `Object List>List All` menu. I guess the way that the indicator is written has hid them from the chart. How can I expose these objects from the indicator to the chart?

Here are some relevant bits of my indicator:

```
//--- indicator settings
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 6
#property indicator_plots 6

#property indicator_type1 DRAW_ARROW
#property indicator_width1 5
#property indicator_color1 0xFFAA00
#property indicator_label1 "Buy"

#property indicator_type2 DRAW_ARROW
#property indicator_width2 5
#property indicator_color2 0x0000FF
#property indicator_label2 "Sell"

#property indicator_type3 DRAW_ARROW
#property indicator_width3 5
#property indicator_color3 0xFFAA00
#property indicator_label3 "Buy"

#property indicator_type4 DRAW_ARROW
#property indicator_width4 5
#property indicator_color4 0x0000FF
#property indicator_label4 "Sell"

#property indicator_type5 DRAW_ARROW
#property indicator_width5 5
#property indicator_color5 0x00FFFB
#property indicator_label5 "CLOSE BUY"

#property indicator_type6 DRAW_ARROW
#property indicator_width6 5
#property indicator_color6 0x00FFFB
#property indicator_label6 "CLOSE SELL"

//--- indicator buffers
double Buffer1[];
double Buffer2[];
double Buffer3[];
double Buffer4[];
double Buffer5[];
double Buffer6[];

datetime time_alert; //used when sending alert
input bool Audible_Alerts = true;
double myPoint; //initialized in OnInit
int MA_handle;
double MA[];
int MA_handle2;
double MA2[];
int MACD_handle;
double MACD_Signal[];
int MA_handle3;
double MA3[];
double Close[];
int MA_handle4;
double MA4[];
int MA_handle5;
double MA5[];
int MA_handle6;
double MA6[];
double Open[];

.
.
.

int OnInit()
  {   
   SetIndexBuffer(0, Buffer1);
   PlotIndexSetDouble(0, PLOT_EMPTY_VALUE, EMPTY_VALUE);
   PlotIndexSetInteger(0, PLOT_ARROW, 241);
   SetIndexBuffer(1, Buffer2);
   PlotIndexSetDouble(1, PLOT_EMPTY_VALUE, EMPTY_VALUE);
   PlotIndexSetInteger(1, PLOT_ARROW, 242);
   SetIndexBuffer(2, Buffer3);
   PlotIndexSetDouble(2, PLOT_EMPTY_VALUE, EMPTY_VALUE);
   PlotIndexSetInteger(2, PLOT_ARROW, 241);
   SetIndexBuffer(3, Buffer4);
   PlotIndexSetDouble(3, PLOT_EMPTY_VALUE, EMPTY_VALUE);
   PlotIndexSetInteger(3, PLOT_ARROW, 242);
   SetIndexBuffer(4, Buffer5);
   PlotIndexSetDouble(4, PLOT_EMPTY_VALUE, EMPTY_VALUE);
   PlotIndexSetInteger(4, PLOT_ARROW, 251);
   SetIndexBuffer(5, Buffer6);
   PlotIndexSetDouble(5, PLOT_EMPTY_VALUE, EMPTY_VALUE);
   PlotIndexSetInteger(5, PLOT_ARROW, 251);
   //initialize myPoint
   myPoint = Point();
   if(Digits() == 5 || Digits() == 3)
     {
      myPoint *= 10;
     }
   MA_handle = iMA(NULL, PERIOD_CURRENT, 1, 0, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE);
   if(MA_handle < 0)
     {
      Print("The creation of iMA has failed: MA_handle=", INVALID_HANDLE);
      Print("Runtime error = ", GetLastError());
      return(INIT_FAILED);
     }

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrows can be drawn as objects (in such a case you can find such objects when checking for the objects, select All because they can be hidden), or as indicator buffers. In your case, it looks like arrows are buffers because your indicator initializes buffers. In order to get data, you need to use `iCustom` function.

Comment: How would I use the iCustom to access the buffer containing the arrow objects in say an EA?

Comment: https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/indicators/icustom or check ready-made MACD EA in MT5 sdk

Comment: Based on your recommendation I updated  my code (https://pastebin.com/Tf6tH62u) to check the `CopyBuffer()` value, but the value always equal to the `CopyBuffer()` count parameter. For example in the updated code linked in this comment, the count is 123 and the `CopyBuffer()` value is also 123 regardless of the timeframe.